# SuperSocket Silverlight policy server not being hit and policy not downloaded

Tags: c#, silverlight, owin, supersocket.net

I'm using the SuperSocket Socket Service (SuperSocket.SocketService.exe) as my Silverlight policy server but the **service is not being hit and my policy not returned**. I can connect to the service through Hercules however.

I've enabled the built in Flash Silverlight policy server by adding it to my configuration file as explained [here](http://docs.supersocket.net/v1-6/en-US/The-Built-in-Flash-Silverlight-Policy-Server-in-SuperSocket). The SuperSocket.Facility.dll exists in my service's run directory along with 3 other required dlls.

Service configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="superSocket" type="SuperSocket.SocketEngine.Configuration.SocketServiceConfig, SuperSocket.SocketEngine" />
    </configSections>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="ServiceName" value="SupperSocketService" />
    </appSettings>
<superSocket>
    <servers>
        <server name="SilverlightPolicyServer"
                serverType="SuperSocket.Facility.PolicyServer.SilverlightPolicyServer, SuperSocket.Facility"
                ip="Any" port="943"
                receiveBufferSize="32"
                maxConnectionNumber="100"
                policyFile="D:\policyserver\SLPolicy.xml"
                clearIdleSession="true">
        </server>
    </servers>
</superSocket>
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
</startup>
```

The policy server starts fine:

[image]

Connection from Silverlight which **fails**:

```
var webSocketClient = new WebSocket(string.Format("ws://127.0.0.1:{0}/websocket", 943, "basic", version));            
webSocketClient.Opened += new EventHandler(webSocketClient_Opened);
webSocketClient.Closed += new EventHandler(webSocketClient_Closed);
webSocketClient.DataReceived += new EventHandler<DataReceivedEventArgs>(webSocketClient_DataReceived);
webSocketClient.MessageReceived += new EventHandler<MessageReceivedEventArgs>(webSocketClient_MessageReceived);

if (autoConnect)
{
    webSocketClient.Open();

    if (!OpenedEvent.WaitOne(1000))
        throw new Exception("Cannot connect...");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I never got to resolve the problem and aborted this project for various reasons.

I've rewritten it using MEAN JS.